# Rails Object#blank? vs. String#empty? confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string

[Rails docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-blank%3F) have this information for `Object#blank?`

> An object is blank if it’s false, empty, or a whitespace string. For example, “”, “ “, nil, [], and {} are blank.

But the source for that method is like this:

```
# File activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/blank.rb, line 12
def blank?
    respond_to?(:empty?) ? empty? : !self
end
```

Now, when I open my handy little command line and type `ruby -e 'p "       ".empty?'` it returns false. That means that Rails should say this is a blank value when it's clearly not. But! I open my `rails console` and I type `"      ".empty?` and get false like my earlier straight command line. But, I type "       ".blank? and I get true like Rails promises me.

What am I missing in understanding how Rails' `blank?` method works with the `empty?` method of String?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rails is kinda tricky in how it documents its `blank?` method. Even though `Object#blank?` claims to also detect whitespace strings, it is implemented with `String#blank?` to handle the whitespace case and `Object#blank?` to catch the generic case. (`blank?` is defined on a few other classes, too, to save time.)

[activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/blank.rb, line 66](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/blank.rb#L66):

```
class String
  def blank?
    self !~ /\S/
  end
end
```

Comment: Ah, thanks! As soon as SO will let me I'll mark yours as the answer.