# Is there a Ruby string#blank? method?

Tags: ruby

`String#blank?` is very useful, but exists in Rails, not Ruby.

Is there something like it in Ruby, to replace:

```
str.nil? || str.empty?
```

Comment: I dont see anything like that in the reference http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html

Comment: See this answer for some information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819899/rails-objectblank-vs-stringempty-confusion

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247948/is-there-a-better-way-of-checking-nil-or-length-0-of-a-string-in-ruby

Comment: If there were such thing in Ruby, then Rails would not have come up with it.

Comment: `String#blank?` is **not** equivalent to testing for `nil?` or `empty?`, as it returns `true` for strings with only spaces.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

AFAIK there isn't anything like this in plain Ruby. You can create your own like this:

```
class NilClass
  def blank?
    true
  end
end

class String
  def blank?
    self.strip.empty?
  end
end
```

This will work for `nil.blank?` and `a_string.blank?` you can extend this (like rails does) for true/false and general objects:

```
class FalseClass
  def blank?
    true
  end
end

class TrueClass
  def blank?
    false
  end
end

class Object
  def blank?
    respond_to?(:empty?) ? empty? : !self
  end
end
```

References:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2a371368c91789a4d689d6a84eb20b238c37678a/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/blank.rb#L57
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2a371368c91789a4d689d6a84eb20b238c37678a/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/blank.rb#L67
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2a371368c91789a4d689d6a84eb20b238c37678a/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/blank.rb#L14
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2a371368c91789a4d689d6a84eb20b238c37678a/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/blank.rb#L47

And here is the `String.blank?` implementation which should be more efficient than the previous one:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2a371368c91789a4d689d6a84eb20b238c37678a/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/blank.rb#L101

Comment: That implementation could be made more inefficient. Try it on `' a very very long string......'` just for fun!

Comment: Is it a poor practice to extend NilClass?

Comment: @BSeven Yes, and this solution doesn't work on the variety of objects that the Rails method does. Also, as pointed out by Marc-Andre, `strip` is a bit inefficient (especially when you throw away the output)

Comment: @MarkThomas what do you mean by variety of objects? The last link in my answer is exactly what you've copied in your answer.

Comment: Thanks for updating it. This is a better answer now. One minor nit: you don't need separate patches for `TrueClass` and `FalseClass` because the `!self` part takes care of it automatically.

Answer (score 4):

You can always do exactly what Rails does. If you look at [the source to `blank`](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/blank?), you see it adds the following method to `Object`:

```
# File activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/blank.rb, line 14
  def blank?
    respond_to?(:empty?) ? empty? : !self
  end
```

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that the code has been adjusted to `respond_to?(:empty?) ? !!empty? : !self` in newer versions.

Comment: @someuser, you are correct. In Rails, the above is applied to `Object` to be able to handle `blank?` for anything. However, it does depend on a defined `String#blank?` which accounts for strings with spaces. You can use `self !~ /\S/` for that. Not sure why I didn't catch that on this 5-year old post. Guess I'm older and wiser now :)

Answer (score 3):

What about something like:

`str.to_s.empty?`

Comment: how about `str.to_s.strip.empty?`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your string can be stripped, what's wrong with `str.nil? or str.strip.empty?` as in the following:

```
2.0.0p0 :004 > ' '.nil? or ' '.strip.empty? 
 => true
```

Comment: This isn't enough since, for example, nil.blank? should return true

Comment: cause I didn't know about strip.

Comment: I've taken your comments into account and enhanced the answer.

Comment: Using `strip` can be very inefficient in this case.

Answer (score 2):

No such function exist in Ruby, but there is an active proposal for `String#blank?` on [ruby-core](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/8206).

In the meantime, you can use this implementation:

```
class String
  def blank?
    !include?(/[^[:space:]]/)
  end
end
```

This implementation will be very efficient, even for very long strings.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone new looking for this, can use [simple_ext](https://github.com/kumartushar/simple_ext/) gem. This gem helps you to use all the Ruby core extensions on objects like Array, String, Hash etc. from rails.

```
require 'simple_ext'
str.blank?
arr.blank?
... etc.
```