# Silly query on difference between nil, ' ' , '' specific to ruby language

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

Can anyone tell me when to use either nil, ' ', '' . Like i want to match database column which is not populated in rails/ruby. So i am not understanding which to match like ..

`if var == nil` or `if var == ' '` or `if var== ''` . I always tried hit and trial but now i want to clarify it now.

Comment: A database `NULL` is usually mapped to a Ruby `nil` and vice-versa. But if the db column in question does not allow NULLs, you will have to check for whatever the default value is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are three *different* values.

`nil` is a value that "represents nothing", it is the only value of `NilClass`. With few exceptions `nil` should be used to represent things like NULL or "value missing"; and this is how it is mapped in ActiveRecord (`NULL<->nil`).

`''` is an empty string, such that `''.size == 0`. A non-NULL text column in a database might return an empty string; a non-NULL column should never be mapped to `nil`, as it can't represent NULL values.

`' '` is a string containing a single space. It's really no more special than `'foo'` as it's just a string representing some data; the data just happens to be entirely whitespace.

---

As Phlip was hinting at, [`Object#blank?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819899/rails-objectblank-vs-stringempty-confusion), a method added by Rails/AS, can be used to test for all of these cases simultaneously.

```
x.blank?  # true if x is: false, nil, '', '    '
```

(However, IMOHO, code eliminating `nil` or `''` distinctions from a database result-set is already broken and the data/model should be suspect. NULL-ability and multiplicity are huge concepts in relational databases..)

Comment: And what does `' '.blank?` return?

Comment: so ..in database if column is not present ...it should be mapped to NilClass right ?

Comment: @Phlip http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819899/rails-objectblank-vs-stringempty-confusion - it's added by RoR and is not standard Ruby. In any case, searching for the specific question usually yields results.

Comment: what will be main difference between Nil and '' ? Nil is mostly used in databases ? ..Need some clarification

Comment: @RahulInsane No, it should likely be an *exception* (but it depends on the *actual operation used*). If the database column *is present*, but *has a NULL value*, that will normally be mapped to `nil`.

Comment: @Phlip Oh, I see. You're were suggesting that I answer the question that he *didn't* ask :|

Answer (score 2):

It probably depends on how the data is stored in the database.  Likely, `NULL` values in the database will be represented by ruby `nil`.  Depending on the schema, these values may instead by represented by empty strings "".  It would be unusual (though possible) to set the default value of a database text field to " ".  So, in short, the value you should be testing depends on databse schema.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, Try  to use blank? method. Any valueless things are blanks.
nil has value? Sure, it is not:

```
nil.blank? => true
```

Empty strings, like "  "  => did not provide any usefull value, right? They are blank too:

```
"  ".blank? => true
```

**p.s**.: blank? is an 'active_support' extension, if you need it in pure ruby, include it as a module:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'active_support/core_ext/object/blank'
```